# Bits to Byte in C++

Tags: c++, byte, bit

I'm trying to:

1. convert a group of 8 integers, all of value 0 or 1, into a byte
2. reverse the bit order of that byte
3. print the value of that byte (in what format?) ( i can guess until i have it right here )

Also, I'm not allowed to use the STL for this problem.

Comment: you're supposed to have tried something, and got stuck by a bug, and then ask your question with said code. Could you please provide the code giving you problems?

Comment: Look at std::bitset, it may help you with this.

Comment: Can you check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776) first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to reverse the bits in a byte. That is, the bits should move so:

```
from: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
to:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

This code will do it, inelegantly - you can find much better algorithms if you search. Can you see how it works though?

```
uint8_t reverse_bits(uint8_t byte)
{
    return ((byte & 0x01) << 7)
          |((byte & 0x02) << 5)
          |((byte & 0x04) << 3)
          |((byte & 0x08) << 1)
          |((byte & 0x10) >> 1)
          |((byte & 0x20) >> 3)
          |((byte & 0x40) >> 5)
          |((byte & 0x80) >> 7);
}
```

Comment: Can you build the byte yourself now?

Comment: I suggest asking a fresh question if you're stuck - post just the byte-building code you have, and say what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

A simple method is to mask rest of bits, as you can see in [way to read individual bits](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m287351.aspx).

Comment: This link had the answer it too, can up tyou